# Converting a point in a finite field to its real (x, y) coordinate

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let curve $A = y^2 = x^3 + 3$ and curve $B = y^2 \equiv x^3 + 3 \pmod{19}$

Let $G$ be the positive y-valued point in the curve where $x = 2$

Let $r$ be a random scalar integer, for example, $r = 5$

Compute the point $G*r$ in both curves $A$ and $B$

Now, assume I give you the point $G*r$ in curve $B$, can you find what my point $G*r$ in curve $A$ is? You don't know the value for $r$, but you do know all other parameters. You can't bruteforce the curve.

Comment: You should tell us exactly what the original problem was that led you to this question. Beyond that, there’s a problem, ’cause there is no “the” point in characteristic zero that will correspond to a point with coordinates in $\Bbb Z/16\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Lubin its just curiosity. I've also changed the curve which now leads to a group of prime order n=13.

Comment: I am puzzled by this question. If the coordinates of a point $(x,y)$ are in a finite field, then they are elements of that finite field. They are not real numbers at all.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I hope the edit helps.

Comment: Improved, sure. Thanks! There are still a few obstacles. By your specification $y=\sqrt{11}$. In the field $\Bbb{F}_{19}$ we can then have $y=\pm7$, but there is no unique way to say which it should be. Remember that in finite fields we do not have any kind of notions of *positive* or *larger than*. More generally, there is no general way to relate a  point $(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2$ to a point over a finite field. What is usually done is that we have a suitable subfield $K$ of $\Bbb{R}$ that is also a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: (cont'd) Then we concentrate on those points that have coordinates in the  subfield $K$. More often than not (not 100 per cent about this, corrections welcome), we assume that $x,y$ are algebraic integers of $K$. Here the choice $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{11})$ works just fine, and $(x,y)=(2,\sqrt{11})\in K^2$. To associate with such a point a point with coordinates in a finite field of characteristic $19$ we do the following. We pick a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ such that $19\in\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: (cont'd) Then the quotient ring $F=\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$ will be a finite field of characteristic $19$ as required. As $x,y$ are assumed to be elements of $\mathcal{O}_K$, their cosets in $F$ are well defined. Furthermore, if $(x,y)$ is on curve $A$, the image $(x+\mathfrak{p},y+\mathfrak{p})$ will be on curve $B$, because the projection map is a homomorphism of rings.

Comment: (cont'd) With that (known as *reduction modulo $\mathfrak{p}$*) preliminary out of the way we, at least, have a way of relating some points on $A$ with points on $B$. This relation actually preserves the group operation of the elliptic curves. So if $P$ is a point (with coordinates in $K$) on curve $A$, and $\overline{P}$ is its image on curve $B$, we have the rule $\overline{r*P}=r*\overline{P}$.

Comment: (cont'd) And I can finally describe why the question is not too well defined. You see, the point $\overline{G}$ on curve $B$ has a finite order, say $\ell$. Meaning that knowing $r*\overline{G}$ does not specify $r$. We have
$$r_1*\overline{G}=r_2*\overline{G}$$ whenever $r_1\equiv r_2\pmod{\ell}$. But, more often than not, the points $r_1*G$ and $r_2*G$ are distinct. Basically I am saying that there are infinitely many points on $A$ that become a given point of $B$ when they are reduced modulo $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: (cont'd) It may well turn out that there is a unique (or only relatively few) such point with coordinates in $\mathcal{O}_K$. But I'm not sure we can do all of the above? Even if forgetting about the uncertainty in $r$. For example, the calculation of $r*G$ often takes us outside of $\mathcal{O}_K$. We can switch to projective coordinates, but at some point the non-uniqueness of $r$ will ruin the day.

Comment: While typing all of the above I did realize that there is an interesting lifting property that can possibly be solved. I'm still fairly sure that the non-uniqueness of $r$ will ruin this, for example, as an attack on the related DLP.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. Wow. First of all, thank you for developing so much your answer. I get what you mean by the non-uniqueness of $r$, but what if we only try to solve for the smallest positive $r$ integer and ignore all the other solutions? Could we convert this way points from curve $B$ to the corresponding lowest $G*r$ point in curve $A$?

Comment: Cross-Posted with [Crytpgraphy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87700/18298). This is not considered good in [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/403350)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question (as in [rev. 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3994923/3)), it can be shown by enumeration that there are 12 solutions to $y^2 \equiv x^3 + 3\pmod{19}$ :
$$\begin{array}{}
(1,2),&(2,7),&(3,7),&(7,2),&(11,2),&(14,7)\\
(1,17),&(2,12),&(3,12),&(7,17),&(11,17),&(14,12)
\end{array}$$
Thus with the neutral element $\infty$ (aka point at infinity), the order of curve $B$ is $12+1=13$. The point $B$ has the same $x=2$ coordinate on curves $A$ and $B$. We get $y=\sqrt{11}$ on $A$, and¹ $y=7$ on $B$.

Point addition $R\gets P+Q$ can go by the same formulas for $A$ and $B$, with addition, multiplication, division², and equality in the field $\mathbb R$ for $A$, the field $\mathbb F_{19}$ for $B$:

- If $P=\infty$, $R\gets Q$.
- Otherwise, if $Q=\infty$, $R\gets P$.
- Otherwise, if $x_P\ne x_Q$
  $$\begin{align}
  \lambda&\gets\frac{y_Q-y_P}{x_Q-x_P}\\
  x_R&\gets\lambda^2-x_P-x_Q\\
  y_R&\gets\lambda(x_P-x_R)-y_R
  \end{align}$$
- Otherwise, if $P=Q$ (that is $x_P=x_Q$ and $y_P=y_Q$)
  $$\begin{align}
  \lambda&\gets\frac{3{x_P}^2}{2y_P}\\
  x_R&\gets\lambda^2-2x_P\\
  y_R&\gets\lambda(x_P-x_R)-y_R
  \end{align}$$
- Otherwise (that is $x_P=x_Q$ and $y_P\ne y_Q$), $R\gets\infty$.

In order to compute $G*5$ on each curve, we can compute $G_2\gets G+G$, $G_4\gets G_2+G_2$, $G*5\gets G_4+G$ per these formulas. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVRdb5swFH3nV3g8Jalpm0R7WDNPClNXdVI3u3lEBEEgLYIAI7DiIH57dm0IOOkqgYTv1zn33It3bvEa7Nwi3LjHo3b/naZhUtzdlXv3JSB6d7Yq7NnIK8PY3yMXZcKG0gTlgRujTZn/DZCH@HpGqvX8yrtGQ1rt4az5X@ou9cvYzbvsPlfYUXatL7S@hgNFHJw5jX1HzDjdRFZ9IDR9C/Kn1AeIOc7sK6/Bj1vrp7tJvXDFd14aWwewf73Fj8k2TMKC47oNz2zcJx/w9GYGlsa2zwA9R8WSxGT9w1m9Cq/@5IV1aNMhf@n7inJwsuqKYk4biGWYs0ao6PoghJRhjyhyEx8xoUenomxcZPYwzMGCDevs1BkYCDvVeiQHoByJBV9MfF3qVhGpATOAFujA5ZEzg4uj7LD6RG5xGzbq3EjR2piKvMwer2fGqKJXFRvDaQFSyFAwGdVYKcfJZTnxziu6FrKfCiNrBilq7Zkk@FHdrn@7ndpH3csh/ijjeBXusjjccqtXoVWAE9m62veI35BKEBCATOAP2GpD0Ixs4mYEzMcd43fhA892P57CRNkPOFlUbEQeFGWe7JFBLxdBhCjTJqfvk6@GXeXKoInccUMuOW8uo0AQUoNTeISrjFU2ZWxF@JxPNHnPCMKcx6QIXoL8fBHPuIlifRjtfiiQL/o2xd0UGGnjzLBYvYbb4jl8eS2AwtTG3aZLNvBI4X/7PrOiwceEj9m28EXwW7bFjAgPwopHeMVoqToNTRtN9PvKhbUIULkP9MlYy8nnhbYk84VGc3EL6A9LhIiOH5bkdDHM8FIMsvdPcvA/d23kEHnmR0jm/7KebayjkZtleVqFcNMGMR/rEGeSeo6nX5qhokkQAkRTQTRVRFMi9nim9B6P/wA). We get
$$\begin{align}
G*r&=\left(\frac{60503882}{151321},-\frac{141898736429 \sqrt{11}}{58863869}\right)&\text{ on curve }A\\
&\approx(399.838,-7995.14)\\
\\
G*r&=(7,2)&\text{ on curve }B
\end{align}$$

In general, we don't know how to compute $G*r$ on curve $A$ from $G*r$ on curve $B$ other than by finding $r$ first. If we could, that would³ allow finding $r$, which would solve the discrete logarithm problem on a (non-singular) elliptic curve on $\mathbb F_p$ in time polynomial w.r.t. $\log p$. That feat is widely conjectured impossible with a classical Turing machine, and the basis of the conjectured security of Elliptic Curve cryptography, e.g. on [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#page=13).

---

¹ Finding a modular square root of $11$ and taking "positive" as $\in[0,9]$. Square roots in the field $\mathbb F_p$ can be efficiently computed even when prime $p$ is large, see the [Tonelli–Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm).

² Division $\frac uv$ in field $\mathbb F_{19}$ can be computed as $v^{-1}\,u$ where the modular inverse $v^{-1}$ can be found using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Modular_integers).

³ If we get the coordinates of $G*r$ accurately enough.